# scale_x_date in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm rather new to R, but I am trying to use `scale_x_date` within the `ggplot2` package to create a hydrograph for my thesis.  The hydrograph consists of predicted and actual values which are depths in the river I am working on.  I want to be able to change the date labeling and breaks. Here is what I have.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
LowerHydro<-data.frame(LowerHydrology)
LowerHydro$date <- as.Date(LowerHydro$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
attach(LowerHydro)
p<-ggplot(data=LowerHydro,aes(x=date,y=Depth,group=Group,color=Group))
p+geom_line()+scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%y"),breaks=date_breaks("3 months"))
```

but after the last line of code, I get the following error:

```
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
unused argument(s) (labels = function (x)
```

if I just run the last line of code as follows without labels =, just with breaks =, I still get an error:

```
p+geom_line()+scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("3 months"))
Error in cut.default(days, c(0, 10, 56, 365, 730, 5000, Inf), labels = FALSE) :
'x' must be numeric
```

here is my str(LowerHydro)

```
data.frame':    712 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Depth: num  5.24 5.14 5.42 5.27 5.27 ...
$ Group: Factor w/ 2 levels "Actual","Predicted": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ date : Date, format: "2010-10-01" "2010-10-02" ...
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.9 proto_0.3-9.2 reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.5.2    scales_0.2.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.1-0   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.0       munsell_0.3       
[5] RColorBrewer_1.0-5 stringr_0.4        tools_2.13.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Don't use attach. There is no need here, as you are passing `lowerHydro` as the `data` argument to `ggplot`, and you will just get confused anyway. Also, should `x = date`  be `x = Date`? (note the capitalization) within the call to `ggplot`. I think this second point is your actual problem here as your data doesn't have a `date` column.

Comment: sorry my stats professor actually helped with the code and created a new variable called date...I edited the code to just change the existing Date variable to as.Date..whereas in his code the fourth line is LowerHydro$date <- as.Date(LowerHydro$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")....the line of code will not work whether I use the new variable date or in the case of the code I posted, Date.

Comment: i still get the same errors with the plot, but your right x=Date....but that is not the issue.

Comment: Can you at least show how `date` was created then? At the moment this question is not reproducible

Comment: edited the code.....date was just created in the fourth line of code as per my professor....I thought there was no need to create a date variable as Date could be just used.  The edited code reflects how date was created from the original column variable Date....More specifically this is how date was created....LowerHydro$date <- as.Date(LowerHydro$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y").

Comment: it does matter whether I run LowerHydro$date <- as.Date(LowerHydro$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") and put x=date in the ggplot argument.....or I run LowerHydro$Date <- as.Date(LowerHydro$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")....and put x=Date in the ggplot argument....it still does not like what I am doing in scale_x_date as far as labels and breaks.

Comment: I cannot replicate this with ggplot2 version `0.9.3.99`. Can you include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question.

Comment: i added the session info

Comment: Try updating `ggplot` and `scales` -- there have been major changes and bug fixes since ggplot2 0.8.9, especially to the way `ggplot` and `scales` interact

Comment: dumb question...how do I update those packages???  If I go to tools->check for package updates, neither one of those packages pop up on the list of available packages for updating....if I go to install packages and select ggplot2, in installs the same version I have currently.

Comment: You need to upgrade R first. You're using 2.13—it's up to 2.15 now. You should be able to update `ggplot` and everything else after that.

Comment: You will need to update R as well --- 2.15.2 is the current version, 2.13.0 is two years old (and at least 4 versions). The most uptodate versions of packages will (often) require an up-to-date version of R.

Comment: yeah sorry thats just what I was thinking.  Updating R as we speak...sorry

Comment: the code works with the updated version of R and the updated packages ggplot2 and scales...thanks alot mnel...really appreciate it.